# store Javascript code in PHP variable?

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to store JavaScript code in a PHP variable, in order to inject it multiple times into my main code:

```
<?php

$PASSME = <<<PASSME
alert("hello world");
PASSME;

echo "<a onclick=$PASSME >Click here</a>";

?>
```

In Google Chrome I can read this source code:

```
<a onclick="alert("hello" world");>Click here</a>
```

So I noticed this:

`"hello" world"` should be `"hello world"`

What am I doing wrong?

**NB:** I am actually working on a more complex project. I tried to make an example in order to understand how to correctly do it.

Comment: Also, try to see the same page using View Source in Chrome and not in console. I think you might see where is the error there.

Comment: U used double quotes in double quotes

Comment: syntax highlighting even shows you where the error is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following (You missed Quotes around variable)

```
 <?php

$PASSME = <<<PASSME
alert("hello world");
PASSME;

echo "<a onclick='".$PASSME."' >Click here</a>";

?>
```

Comment: Are you talking about '".$PASSME."'  ?

Comment: yes, sorry for my ignorant question. why `'".$PASSME."'` and not just `".$PASSME."` ?

Comment: See Consider it as 3 blocks of Statement=>                                  1)"<a onclick='"        2).$passme.   3) "'Click here</a>"                     Now see  First part rendered as=>    <a onclick='                      Then Second part rendered as appending Variable (php variable) after Single quote after onclick                                          Then finally Code rendered as => '>Click here </a>                          So finally IT GETS rendered as <a onclick="alert(&quot;hello world&quot;);">Click here</a> in Browser.  ITS about Rendering HTML in browser

Comment: thanks I was actually wondering why I need to enclose the $PASSME variable into ' ' and not pass it just like as is, without apostrophes/single quotes. in short: why do I need quotes around the variable? because this way it gets parsed as a string?

Comment: See there are 2 parts in Code here ,1)static 2) Dynamic                                    1)Static code is printed on Browser as it is (Without processing)        2)Dynamic part is First processed ,And then Inserted inside Static part (Here Dynamic code is $passme) . if you Dont give Quotes around $passme,Browser does not understand its meaning ,and it will print it as it is ($passme as plain) .But if its inside Quotes ,Browser knows its Variable (Dynamic part,Special part),So it processes and then inserts into static Code .

Comment: ok thank you very much @user3326275 i do really appreciate your help. i now wish you choose a nickname , haha

Comment: I helped pretty well, still I got 0 Upvotes (points),this is not OK.

Comment: I voted your answer up, but evidently someone else downvoted it, having it result in 0.

Comment: Ok ,ITS fine ,First you upvoted=>+10 ,Then best answer=>+15 ,Then downvoted by someone =>-2 ,No problem ,its loss of 2 only :) Thnks

Answer (score 1):

As I commented you used double quoetes in double quotes, use single quotes instead:

```
<?php

$PASSME = <<<PASSME
alert('hello world');
PASSME;

echo "<a onclick=\"$PASSME\" >Click here</a>";

?>
```

This will result in correct code:

```
<a onclick="alert('hello world');">Click here</a>
```

When having a lot of code, just pass variables from php to js, ie:

```
<?php

$PASSME = <<<PASSME
var message = 'hello world'
PASSME;
?>
<script>
<?= $PASSME; ?>
</script>
<?
echo "<a onclick=\"alert(message)\">Click here</a>";
?>
```

Comment: thank you although i have a complex code with single and double quotes, all nested. it would be very hard to escape every quote..

Comment: That will not generate the code you say it will. The `"` characters will be missing from the generated HTML because they don't exist in the PHP. Then it will fail because the space will terminate the attribute value.

Comment: Jess if you have a lot of complex code, it is much better to keep it in separate js, and just pass variables from php to js.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your attribute value contains space characters and is not delimited with quote characters.

```
<?php
  $html_safe_passme = htmlspecialchars($PASSME, ENT_QUOTES);
?>
<a onclick="<?php echo $html_safe_passme; ?>">Click here</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately I am getting the same result!

Comment: I just tested this with your original definition of `$PASSME` at http://writecodeonline.com/php/ and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `"` to `&quot;` in the HTML attribute value. You also need to delimit the attribute value with double-quotes (which mustn't be encoded) because it contains spaces, like so:

(Also, personally I wouldn't use PHP's `<<<` for strings)

```
$passme = "alert(&quot;hello world&quot;);";

echo "<a onclick=\"$passme\">click here</a>";
```

Comment: there is no need to change the  echo statement.both works fine and same.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this, with single quotes:

```
alert('hello world');
```

Comment: Single quotes won't help. The HTML attribute value will still be terminated on the space.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

$PASSME = "alert('hello&nbsp;world');";

echo "<a onclick=". $PASSME . " >Click here</a>";

?>
```

try to add `&nbsp;` to change space in your code. and DONE!

Comment: thank you, that's good code, although I actually have complex JavaScript code, with nested quotes. so I should declare the PHP variable in [HereDoc format](http://it1.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Comment: @JessStone how about echo "<a onclick='alert(&quot;hello world&quot;)'>Click here</a>";